# Is a closure executed when setting it to a variable?

Tags: swift

I'm making a wrapper for our API. The idea is all routes defined as enums, and returning an `Alamofire` `DataResponse` object to wherever it's called.

An example of this pattern:

```
//MARK: PUT requests
@discardableResult
static func put(_ route: API.Route.put) -> DataRequest {
    var request: () -> DataRequest
    switch route {
    case .location(let location):
        let params = ["lat":location.coordinate.latitude, "long":location.coordinate.longitude]
        let url = baseUrl + endpoint(for: route)
        request = { Alamofire.request(url, method: .put, parameters: params) } //<< Is this block executed as I set it? 
    }
    
    return request().responseJSON(completionHandler: { request in log(request)})
}
```

As I'd like to perform some logging before returning the request, I want to keep the request a closure returning the request as to not start the request until I return it. My thought was that the request closure passed as a variable would not be executed.

However, when I run a similar function in a Playground, it appears to be executed twice. Once when I set it to `request`, and once when I use it.

[image]

If this is the case, I execute the network call twice, which I obviously don't intend.

**Does the closure fire when I set it AND when I call it, or is it just an XCode playground bug?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not executed as you set it.

It's not specifically a Playgrounds bug as much as a result of how Playgrounds displays its results. The *line* (not the closure) is executed twice. Once by assignment, and once when the closure is executed.

You can demonstrate this as follows:

```
func test() -> Int {
    let request: () -> Int
    request =
        { print("run"); return 10 }
    return request()
}

test()
```

Note that "run" is only printed one time.